# NameError (uninitialized constant) with Yourub Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-data-api

When i performance a search with Yourub gem configuration for a youtube video search, the server console returns me the following error message:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

NameError (uninitialized constant ExploreController::Yourub):
  app/controllers/explore_controller.rb:18:in `search'
```

- Added `config/yourub.yml` as showed on the gem site
  https://github.com/edap/yourub

On the explore_controller file we can find this:

```
class ExploreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
  end
  def search
    if params[:queryType] == "users"
      ...
    elsif params[:queryType] == "tracks"
      client = Yourub::Client.new
      client.search(query: params[:queryField]) do |v|
        puts v
      end
      return redirect_to('/explore')
    else
      return redirect_to('/explore')
    end
  end
end
```

> Also added my yourub.yml file here:

```
yourub_defaults: &yourub_defaults
  developer_key: 'apiKey'
  youtube_api_service_name: 'youtube'
  youtube_api_version: 'v3'
  application_name: "apiAplicationName"
  application_version: "0.1"
  log_level: WARN

development:
  <<: *yourub_defaults

production:
  <<: *yourub_defaults

test:
  <<: *yourub_defaults
```

Comment: Might be silly. Did you restart the server after installing the gem?

Comment: :) Thank you Arun Kumar, just what you said, jaja, add ass answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Restart** the server. That should fix the issue.